# Receive jobs results only when ended

Tags: multithreading, powershell, task, jobs

I have a little issue. I'm creating an WPF GUI, with powershell code. I have a function which will perform a task on multiple computers (using parallel workflows). The issue here, is when my task is running, my UI freeze until the task is complete.

I would like to work around with jobs, but i am unable to receive my job when the task is ended.

Here, my simplified function :

```
 parallelPingComputer -ips $ip_list | Select-Object date, Computer, result | out-gridview
```

The function :

```
    workflow parallelPingCOmputer {
    Param($ips)

    foreach -parallel($ip in $ips)
    {
        PingComputer($ip)
    }
}
```

And finally, the "pingcomputer($ip)" is only a ping plus an other task on multiple targets.

I tried to add -AsJob after the parallel ping, and i'm not able to call back the job result when he ended (and not before...)

Can you please help me ? :)

Thank's a lot

Comment: I also tried to take all the code behind a scriptblock of a start-job.

Comment: Can you post the full code, including your GUI?

Comment: Don't use workflows just because you'd like parallel execution of something. Use a RunspacePool or Ping.SendAsync() instead